# django-rest-framework hint:"type error:expect a primary key, but get a ‘dict’"

Tags: python, django, vue.js, django-rest-framework

The questions has bothered me for several days.I have setup a program with django rest framwork. The front end program in 'vue.js'.When 'patch' the data in front end, the server shows '400'. And chrome 'console.log' function shows 'type error:expect a primary key, but get a ‘dict’. 
Followings are details:

*views.py*

```
class MenuConfigViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
print("submitmenu has in")
permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, IsOwnerOrReadOnly)
authentication_classes = (JSONWebTokenAuthentication, SessionAuthentication)
lookup_field = "user_id"

def get_queryset(self):
    return MenuInfo.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)

def get_serializer_class(self):
    if self.action == 'list':
        return MenuInfoSerializer
    else:
        print("hello")
        return MenuSerializer
```

*models.py*

```
class MenuInfo(models.Model):

user = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name="用户")
app_id = models.CharField(default="", max_length=30, verbose_name="app_id", help_text="app_id")
note = models.TextField(default="", verbose_name="备注", help_text="备注")
add_time = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, verbose_name="添加时间")

class Meta:
    verbose_name = "菜单信息"
    verbose_name_plural = verbose_name

def __str__(self):
    return self.user.username


class Button(models.Model):

name = models.CharField(default="", max_length=20, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="菜单名称",
                        help_text="菜单名称")
menuinfo = models.ForeignKey(MenuInfo, related_name='button', blank=True, verbose_name="menuinfo")
type = models.CharField(default="view", max_length=100, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="菜单类型", help_text="菜单类型")
data = models.CharField(default="", max_length=100, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="数据",
                             help_text="数据")
note = models.TextField(default="", verbose_name="备注", help_text="备注")
add_time = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, verbose_name="添加时间")

class Meta:
    verbose_name = "菜单详情"
    verbose_name_plural = verbose_name

def __str__(self):
    return self.name


class Thumb(models.Model):

content = models.CharField(default="NULL", max_length=20, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="图文详情", help_text="图文详情")
menuinfo = models.ForeignKey(MenuInfo, related_name='thumb', blank=True, verbose_name="menuinfo")
url = models.URLField(default="view", max_length=100, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="链接", help_text="链接")
note = models.TextField(default="", max_length=100, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="备注", help_text="备注")
add_time = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, verbose_name=u"添加时间")

class Meta:
    verbose_name = "Thumb"
    verbose_name_plural = verbose_name

def __str__(self):
    return self.content
```

*serializers.py*

```
class MenuInfoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

button=ButtonSerializer(many=True)
thumb=ThumbSerializer(many=True)

class Meta:
    model = MenuInfo
    fields = ("id", "user_id", "button", "thumb")


class MenuSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

user = serializers.HiddenField(
default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault()
)
add_time = serializers.DateTimeField(read_only=True, format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')

class Meta:
    model = MenuInfo
    fields = ("id", "user", "user_id", "button", "thumb", "add_time")
```

Followings are part of codes in front end:

*menuConfig.vue*

```
      submit: function(){
    console.log("here is before submitmenu");
    console.log({
        button:this.menus,
        thumb:this.req[0].thumb,
      });
    this.req[0].button = this.menus;
    console.log(this.req[0]);
    submitmenu( this.req[0].user_id, this.req[0]).then((response)=> {
      alert('修改成功');
      this.getMenuInfo();
      //本地存储用户信息
      //cookie.setCookie('name',this.userName,7);
      //cookie.setCookie('token',response.data.token,7);
      //存储在store
      // 更新store数据
      //that.$store.dispatch('setInfo');
      //跳转到自定义菜单页面
      console.log("push menuconfig page");
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
  },
  getMenuInfo: function() { //请求用户信息
    getMenuDetail().then((response)=> {
          console.log(response.data);
          console.log("above is data");
          console.log(response.data[0].button);
          this.req = response.data;
          this.menus = response.data[0].button;
      }).catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error);
      });
  }
```

api.js

```
export const submitmenu = (user_id, params) => {
return axios.patch(`${host}/menudetail/`+user_id+'/', params)
}

export const getMenuDetail  = () => {
return axios.get(`${host}/menudetail/`)
}
```

When submit menu, the chrome shows following errors, which means 'type error:expected a primary key, but get a dict.'
[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75DG5.jpg)

Comment: It says bad request,which means that you are trying to make a patch request but in backend you expect another type of request.If in backend you have the same type of request then try to clear the cache of chrome and to reload the server.

Comment: But how can I patch a right request? When I request 'getMenuInfo', the server response correctly.  I take the response.data to this.req, then change the data of this.req.  The data type of this.req is not change, finally I patch the request with this.req, then error occurs.  Which part have I make a mistake?